# Why a 'shared mailbox' in Outlook 365 rather than sharing a mailbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, shared-mailbox

In Office 365, Outlook offers [Shared Mailboxes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/about-shared-mailboxes). However, those mailboxes seem to come with plenty of quirks compared to a regular mailbox: no contacts, no add-in, no dedicated credentials for automation, etc.

In terms of scalability, Microsoft indicates that there are performance problems beyond 25 users, which lets me think that a Shared Mailbox is just a regular Outlook mailbox under the hood, with quirks layered on top.

Putting aside the licensing fee for the extra mailbox (Shared Mailbox are free up to 50GB), it seems that *sharing a mailbox* is superior to *a Shared Mailbox* in every dimension.

Are there any feature that are uniquely available on Shared Mailboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your shared mailbox can store up to 50GB of data without you assigning a license to it.

Actually, this is its biggest advantage.

Others, such as permissions and usage methods, are actually similar.